# How to copy field and value within a document to another document in a different collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection called **X** which holds a single document that looks like this:

```
{
    "uid": "dfdf"
}
```

I have another collection called **Y** which also holds a single document that looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "bfbf"
}
```

I want to add to the document from collection **Y**, the field and value from collection X so it will look like this:

```
   {
       "uid": "dfdf",        
       "name": "bfbf"
   }
```

I ran the next code on the Y collection:

```
{$set : {"uid" : {"$query": {"$q": {}, "$ns": "**X**", "$p": "uid"}}}}
```

BUT the value is set with array like this:

```
   {
       "uid": ["dfdf"],        
       "name": "bfbf"
   }
```

How can I set the original value without the array?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the expected behaviour of your `$set`? It seems that currently it is just trying to push all `uid` in collection X into an array of `uid` in collection Y's every documents

Comment: I saw that set is used in order to add new field to a doc. for example: {$set : {"key" : "value"}} so my key is the name of the field from collection x (uid) and the value should be the value of uid from collection X so I performed the a query to get the value of uid from X.  {"$query": {"$q": {}, "$ns": "**X**", "$p": "uid"}} so according to what you are saying, my query is incorrect. do you know which query should I run in order to get the value of uid from X without entring it to an array so it will look like this  
       "uid": "dfdf"
   and not like this 
       "uid": ["dfdf"]

Comment: You are getting an array because you are doing an uncondtional lookup from Y to X. When you have more than one documents in collection X, you will get an array like `["dfdf", "aabb", "ccdd", ...]`in `uid`. If you are simply wanting to merge the fields of documents in the collections, [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Pbe4lSa88s0) could be what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi thanks for the solution but the solution merge all the other fields in the doc as well and I only want the field uid.  if Im going back to my solution with the array. is there a way to add another step to the query and extract the single String from the array ? and then I will get my value? ( in this case for sure the array will only have 1 String)

Comment: You may just need `$unwind` to flatten the array like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6_PEevaFwgV)..? I am still not sure if I am understanding correctly..

Comment: YES! it worked! Thanks you very much. Im new with mongo so I didn't know that there is this operation $unwind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that OP simply want to do unconditional lookup and assign the field `uid` into the collection Y

```js
db.Y.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "X",
      "pipeline": [],
      "as": "x"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$x"
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "uid": "$x.uid"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": "x"
  }
]).forEach(function(doc){
  db.Y.update({_id: doc._id}, {$set: {uid: doc.uid}});
});
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6_PEevaFwgV) for your reference.